# Js. Сортировка по убыванию, в чем ошибка?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

```js
var array = new Array();
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    array[i] = Number(prompt("Press " + i + " number "));
    document.write(array[i] + " ");
}
document.write("<br />"); 

var k = 0;
var a = 0;
var o = Number(1); 
var max = array[a];

for(j=1; j<5; j++){
    for(i = o; i < 5; i++) { 
        if(max < array[i]) { 
            max = array[i]; 
            k = i;
     } 
    }
    var obmen = array[a];   
    array[a] = max;
    array[k] = obmen;
    a = a+1;
    o = o+1;
}

document.write("<br />"); 
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 document.write(array[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: а с чего ты взял, что тут ошибка?

Comment: Ну, не сортирует он массив)

Comment: `[1, 2, 3].sort((a, b) => b - a)` не вариант?

Comment: Неа, так легко))

Comment: что это за алгоритм то?

Comment: нафига вообще эти `o+1` когда всю жизнь второй цикл пускали как `for( i = j + 1; i < N; j++)`. если это пузырек, конечно. и `a` всегда равное `j` на кой?

Comment: Чтобы со  второго раза не трогать 1ый элемент в массиве.

Comment: какой то извращенный алгоритм. написать пузырька со второго элемента, и добавить еще 2 индекса, чтобы нивелировать этот казус.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вроде получается:

```js
var array = [];
var arrayLength = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  array[i] = Number(prompt("Press " + i + " number "));
  document.write(array[i] + " ");
}
document.write("<br />");


for (var j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) {
  var max = array[j]; // максимальное значение (будем всегда ставить в начало)
  var k = j; // индекс текущего максимума
  for (i = j+1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (max < array[i]) {
      max = array[i];
      k = i;
    }
  }
  // ставим максимум на "первую" позицию
  var obmen = array[j];
  array[j] = max;
  array[k] = obmen;
}

document.write("<br />");
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  document.write(array[i] + " ");
```

Comment: Почему "array.length-1" array.length = 5, 5 - 1 = 4. Так всего 3 повторение же получается?

Comment: Строку var k = j; Полагаю можно убрать)

Comment: Когда вы отсортируете предпоследний элемент, то последний сортировать уже не надо будет.

Comment: Нельзя убирать k =j, т.к.тогда некорректно будут работать перестановки.